# Load spark scala script into spark shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to load a spark scala script into a spark shell using load command where the location of the script is passed in a variable. It's not working

```
val scriptLoc="/abc/spark"  
:load ${scriptLoc}/scriptName.scala
```

Even tried like this which didn't work either

```
:load scriptLoc/scriptName.scala
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about `:load s"$scriptLoc/scriptName.scala"`

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you attach the error what you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`spark-shell -i /path/to/file.scala`